# Python - Import package modules before as well as after setup.py install

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, python-import, pypi

Assume a Python package (e.g., `MyPackage`) that consists of several modules (e.g., `MyModule1.py` and `MyModule2.py`) and a set of unittests (e.g., in `MyPackage_test.py`).

```
.
├── MyPackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── MyModule1.py
│   └── MyModule2.py
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    └── MyPackage_test.py
```

I would like to import functions of `MyModule1.py` within the unittests of `MyPackage_test.py`. Specifically, I would like to import the functions both before as well as after package installation via `setup.py install MyPackage`.

Currently, I am using two separate commands, depending on the state before or after package installation:

```
# BEFORE
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'MyPackage'))

# AFTER
import MyPackage
```

Can this be done with a single command?

Comment: May not be exactly what you want but take a look at `python setup.py develop`.

Comment: I do not think this is possible, unless the entry point of the script is the directory with the setup.py file in it. Also refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) post for more info.

Comment: These look like two different imports to me. When extending the `sys.path`, you shouldn't be able to import `MyPackage` at all, only being able to import `MyModule1` etc. What is your original issue? Are you unable to import your package in the tests?

Comment: Interesting question. I'm curious why you would want to do this though. Why would you want to run the unit tests after the package as already been installed?

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**:

It seems that the following command does what I need:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(__file__.split(__info__)[0] + __info__), __info__)
```

**Option 2**:

Depending on the location of `__init__.py`, this also works:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.split(inspect.getfile(MyPackage))[0]))
```

**Option 3**:

Moreover, the [ResourceManager API](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html#id23) seems to offer additional methods.

Answer (score 0):

in pycharm IDE you can can import method easily.by setting the working directory to the folder which contains all files.
And, then in MyPackage `__init__.py` file import all the function from `MyModule1.py` and `MyModule2.py` .
 then in MyPackage_test.py you can use

```
import MyPackage 
from MyPackage import xyz
```