# How to impleent Python's Settings project to an Existing project?

Tags: python-3.x, version-control, scripting, settings

I want to implement **settings** to  my python project, 
Now, the settings.py file holds the hardcoded values of some variables.
I need two types of settings. 
One is Production-based and other one is staging based.
How can I implement it in one file?

Comment: Well, using separate files for settings is a better convention but as you want it in one file, settings can be separated in if else statements while this will be decided via parameter passed in command to run/deploy. for example: define a variable ENVIRONMENT = 'staging'. Then pass its value ('prod' or 'staging') via command.

Answer (score 1):

> in settings.py file:

```
LOCAL = 'local'
STAGING = 'staging'
PRODUCTION = 'prod'

ENVIRONMENT = LOCAL

BASE_URL = 'hello_local/'

if ENVIRONMENT == STAGING:
   # here set url for staging
   BASE_URL = 'hello_staging/'
elif ENVIRONMENT == PRODUCTION:
   # here set url for prod
   BASE_URL = 'hello_prod/'
```

> while running from bash/terminal

```
$ export ENVIRONMENT=staging
$ flask run
```

> or if you are using an IDE like PYCHARM, you can set
>   `ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES` as:

```
ENVIRONMENT = 'staging'
```

Comment: Thanks to @Azeem,
If I am using a settings directory and I wanna import modules from settings package, then how can we do?

Comment: Are you asking about python's "Import system"? If yes, it's simple: 
from settings_folder.settings import ENVIRONMENT
Otherwise check into this post if it helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53648900/python-import-package-modules-before-as-well-as-after-setup-py-install